# I need help finding the 20 closest neighbors to the center a fusion layer

Tags: javascript, variables, google-fusion-tables

I have project in which I am trying to display the 20 closest people in a fusion table to the current center of map with the click of a button. I currently have the the lat and long as a static number, need that to change based on the maps current center. A link for what I currently have is http://www.mappingcenter.org/little_flock/littleflock.html>.

I am new to js and I truly am puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `getCenter()`-method returns the center of a `google.maps.Map`-instance:

```
orderBy:'ST_DISTANCE(geo_latitude, LATLNG('+map.getCenter().lat()+','+map.getCenter().lng()+'))'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using GViz with order by and limit 20.

Query:
"SELECT geometry FROM "+FusionTableID+" ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(geometry, LATLNG("+map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6)+")) LIMIT 10"

[example (with limit 10) which gets the 10 nearest points to a click on the map](http://www.geocodezip.com/orderby_test_gviz_numbered.html)

Comment: this was very helpful as I will be adding markers as the location as well